# On algebraic minimal surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, minimal-surfaces

In the theory of minimal surfaces, we could construct various types of minimal surface based on the way we choose a pair of holomorphic & meromorphic fucntion. To be more specific, let $f(\zeta)$ be a holomorphic function on an open set $U$ in the complex plane, not identically zero while $g(\zeta)$ be a meromorphic function on the same domain such that if $\zeta_0$ is a pole of order $m \geq 1$ of $g$ then it is a zero of order $\geq 2m$ of $f$ then we have a parametrization of a minimal surface
$$\sigma(u,v) = \mathfrak{Re} \int \varphi(\zeta)d\zeta, \zeta = u + iv$$
in which $\sigma$ is a surface patch and $\varphi = \frac{1}{2}(f(1-g^2),if(1+g^2),2fg)$. For example when $(f,g) = (2,\zeta)$ we have the classical Enneper surface
$$\sigma(u,v) = (u - \frac{u^3}{3} + uv^2, -v + \frac{v^3}{3} - u^2v, u^2 - v^2)$$ 
In this [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enneper_surface), I know that the classical Enneper surface is algebraic which means that it can be defined as the zero locus of a polynomial of degree $9$. Naturally, I can generalize this example by choosing $(f,g)=(2,\zeta^n)$ which gives us
$$\sigma(u,v) = (x(u,v),y(u,v),z(u,v)$$
in which 
$$x(u,v) =  u - \frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{2n+1}{2k+1}u^{2k+1}(iv)^{2(n-k)}$$ 
$$y(u,v) =  -v - \frac{1}{2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{2n+1}{2k}u^{2k}i^{2(n+1)-2k}v^{2n+1-2k}$$
$$z(u,v) =   2\sum_{2 \mid k-n-1}\binom{n+1}{k}u^k i^{n+1-k}v^{n+1-k} \ (0 \leq k \leq n+1)$$
and hope these general Enneper surfaces are algebraic. A quick search convinces me that this class of Enneper surfaces are algebraic so I ask for books providing a criterion for determining whether a given minimal surface is algebraic or not, at least in case the pair $(f,g)$ are both polynomials in $\zeta$. Moreover, if it is algebraic then is there an algorithm to derive its defining polynomial-equation?

Other questions, let $\mathcal{S}$ be a algebraic minimal surface (obtained by a pair $(f,g)$ as above) we define $\mathrm{deg}(\mathcal{S})$ to be the least degree of a polynomial (in three variables) defining $\mathcal{S}$.

- Is there a lower bound for $\mathrm{deg}$?
- For a given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, how can we know whether there exists a surface $\mathcal{S}$ with $\mathrm{deg}(\mathcal{S})=n$?

Answer (score 0):

you can see the following 2 papers:
https://www.mdpi.com/2227-7390/6/12/281
Güler E. Family of Enneper Minimal Surfaces. Mathematics. 2018; 6(12):281. https://doi.org/10.3390/math6120281
and
https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/11/1/4
Güler E. The Algebraic Surfaces of the Enneper Family of Maximal Surfaces in Three Dimensional Minkowski Space. Axioms. 2022; 11(1):4.
https://doi.org/10.3390/axioms11010004
Best, Erhan Güler

Comment: These links may provide material that answers the Question, but merely citing the titles and authors doesn't give Readers much indication of how that might be the case.  The usual dictum is to quote the most relevant part of the linked material or summarize in your own words what a Reader should find there.  Since you appear to be the author of both papers, I would think it easy for you to do this, esp. with remarks about the algorithmic approach the Question requests.